# Is 'co.uk' a top level domain?

Tags: domain

Is the combination `co.uk` considered to be a **top level domain**, or is `co.uk` considered to be a **subdomain** of `uk`?

If it is the latter, is the `.uk` domain owned and operated by the same group that owns `co.uk`? This would explain why one can purchase a `*.co.uk` domain (or similar domains, such as `*.org.uk`), but domain registrars do not sell `*.uk` domains on their own.

Comment: Or is my pedantic question ridiculous as everything is a subdomain of `.` anyway?

Comment: The latter; yes, Nominet.  I'm not sure what you mean by "*the two are sold as a pair*".

Comment: @MadHatter By that I mean by going through domain registrars, you can't purchase a `*.uk` domain, instead, you can purchase `.co.uk` or `org.uk`. You have to purchase it "paired" the with `co` prefix.

Comment: What you can or cannot register is not related to the definition of a TLD. (`uk` is the TLD)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The latter.  `.uk` is a CCTLD, or Country Code Top-Level Domain; `.co.uk` is a subdomain thereof.

The whole of the `.uk` namespace is operated by Nominet Ltd.

For many years, direct registration under `.uk` hasn't been allowed, and the namespace has been split into the subdomains we know and love (including `.co.uk`, `.org.uk`, `.net.uk`, `.me.uk`, `.parliament.uk`, and so on) inside which registration was allowed (though not necessarily by everyone; some of those subdomains have very strict registration rules).  But you probably ought to know that - against the wishes of many in the internet community in the UK - Nominet is opening up direct registrations in the `.uk` namespace as of 10 June 2014.  More details can be found at http://www.nominet.org.uk/uk-domain-names/introducing-uk .